# how to detect actual width of span with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to get real width of span in div element that this element has certain width but when I do it give me width of div.

this is my code:

```
<div class="content">
     <span class="type-text" id="tala">my name is marcos kasiri as2215fhkoj</span>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS code:

```
.content {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 200px;
}

.content span {
   display: block;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   color: white;
}
```

please tell me how to get real span value with jquery.

my friends I have one div with width:200px and I write any word in span that this words is bigger as div but this span go on next line.so when I want get this span width show me 200px but I know that this span is bigger of 200px...

Comment: `$('#tala').width()` doesn't work? Also, why use a `<span>` if you make it block-level through CSS?

Comment: Read about [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

Comment: 'get width of span'? where exactly in your code are you 'getting the width of span' ?

Comment: my friends I have one div with width:200px and I write any word in span that this words is bigger as div but this span go on next line.so when I want get this span width show me 200px but I know that this span is bigger of 200px...

Answer (score 4):

By making the element `display:block`, you are essentially telling it to take the full width of its container (since there's nothing else to restrict the width).

Try not making it `display:block`. Try `inline-block` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use $("tala").width() it returns the calculated width of the first element in the set of matched elements. for more information look at [jquery width documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/)